# How do I pass a Range to a Sub in Word VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word, range

I know this sounds simple, but seemingly it is not.

If I write this in Word VBA, it always says "incompatible types" - why?
And how do I make it work?

```
Sub GetRange()
   Dim r As Range
   Set r = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(5).Range

   ProcessRange (r)
End Sub

Sub ProcessRange(r As Range)
    Debug.Print "This generates an error (incompatible types)- why?"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 8):

It is not allowed to call a `Sub` with parenthesis, except if you are using the `Call` statement.

Hence you have to use either:

```
Call ProcessRange(r)
```

Or:

```
ProcessRange r
```

The reason for that is that in VBA (and VBS, VB6, too) the parenthesis can have a whole lot of different meanings.

In your case the range object will be **evaluated** before passing the result to `ProcessRange`. In this case it leads to a `string` being passed to the sub, because the default property of `Range` is `Text`.

See this article for an overview: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Process Range is a `sub` so don't invoke it with parentheses. (The error occurs because `(r)` causes `r` to be evaluated which returns its default property value which isn't of type `range` so mismatches what `ProcessRange` expects.

Use either;

```
ProcessRange r
```

or

```
call ProcessRange(r)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using parenthesis visual basic assumes you're calling a function.

```
ProcessRange r
```

does the trick